# Custom shortcut with alt key not working

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode9

As of Xcode 9 GM, a custom shortcut I had configured for "`Structure > Add Documentation`" stopped working. Instead of the regular behavior, it's now printing `÷` instead. I've read several questions on how to deal with special shortcuts by using Ukelele for example but was wondering if there was another way to use the "old behavior".

Steps:

1. Open Xcode > `Preferences` > `Key Bindings`
2. Search for `add documentation`
3. Set the shortcut to <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> and then press <kbd>↵ enter</kbd>
4. Add a new function, place the cursor immediately above it.
   `function foo(bar: String) {}`
5. Press <kbd>⌥ alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>

Expected:

> New documentation header should be inserted by Xcode
>
> ```
> /// Insert function documentation here !!!
> ///
> /// - parameter bar: Parameter doc
> function foo(bar: String) {}
> ```

Result:

> `÷` is inserted
>
> ```
> ÷
> function foo(bar: String) {}
> ```

Comment: Just followed your steps in the latest version of Xcode 9, and it worked for me. Are you using a QWERTY keyboard with the US layout?

Comment: No. Not really sure what’s going on. It was working fine before the update (Xcode 9 GM + High Sierra last public beta)

Comment: Well the default command to enter `÷` is `Option + /`, which is close to the `Command + Option + /` for the default "insert documentation" shortcut...

Comment: It's working now ¯\_(ツ)_/¯